# How to push, pop, and wrap values in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I've looked high and low and can't figure this one out!

On a page, I have links that have a certain class (plmore). On the same page, I have divs that have a certain class (fcontainer) among others. The number of links with the class plmore will always equal the number of div using the fcontainer class.

My question:

I need to wrap the `div`s that have `fcontainer` class with the links found using plmore.

PSEUDOCODE: 
GET ARRAY OF HREFS
GET ARRAY OF DIV IDS
WRAP DIVS WITH HREFS

This is what I have so far:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var hrefs = new Array();
    $('a.plmore').each(function() {
      hrefs.push($(this).find('a').attr('href'));
    });

    var features = new Array();
    $('fcontainer').each(function() {
      features.push($(this).find('div').attr('id'));
    });

    /* how does one pop from both arrays and wrap?? */
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean like

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    //find all the target anchor elements
    var $as = $('a.plmore');

    //find the div elements
    $('.fcontainer').each(function (idx) {
        //wrap the div at index idx using the href value of anchor element at index idx
        $(this).wrap($('<a/>', {
            href: $as.eq(idx).attr('href')
        }))
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/KQ5GC/)

Comment: It's oh so close! The <a></a> is definitely wrapping the div now - thank you for this! The href attribute doesn't seem to be taking (it doesn't get added to the <a> tag). Any clue why that might be?

Comment: It's alive! You are amazing! Thank you so much! There are a lot of layers of DIVs in this one... I just needed to target a different one. Thank you so much!